# A question in proof of Linnik's Theorem in Arithmetic Large Sieve

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

This question is from course notes in sieve theory and I am struck on this assertion in the proof of Linnik's theorem.

Consider Page 4 of lecture 14 here: [http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html).

Link of lecture 14:[http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015/LargeSieve1.pdf](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015/LargeSieve1.pdf)

I have question in Last line of the proof on page 4: I am not able to deduce how did the author wrote #{ $ p \leq N^{1/2} : n_p > N^{\epsilon} $} equals $\sum_{p\in P}1 $ and how does that is also  $\ll_{\epsilon}$ 1.

Maybe $S(A, P ,\Omega) \gg_{\epsilon} N$ and  $S(A,P, \Omega) \leq 2 N/ S(z)$have to be used but using  $S(A, P ,\Omega) \geq  C_{\epsilon} N$ for some constant $C_{\epsilon}$, I am not getting that $N/ S(z) \ll_{\epsilon} 1$. Instead I am getting : $(C_{\epsilon } N) /2 \leq N/(S(z))$

Can you please help with this ?

Comment: I’m assuming you put a bounty to get more people to try to answer. It may also help just to define the question more. For example, what is $n_p$, is $P$ all primes or a subset, what does $S$ mean in both contexts it’s used, what about C? Anything that makes it less homework for the answerer would generally be appreciated I think.

Comment: @Nico I will take care about it in my other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal{P}$ is by definition the set of prime numbers smaller than $N^{1/2}$ such that all positive integers smaller than $N^\epsilon$ are quadratic residues.
While $n_p$ is the smallest positive integer smaller than p which is NOT a quadratic residue.

The first equality holds because an element in  $\{p \leq N^{1/2} : n_p > N^{\epsilon}\}$ is a prime smaller than $N^{1/2}$ such that the smalelst positive non-quadratic residue is bigger than $N^{\epsilon},$ so it is in $\mathcal{P}.$ And conversely, an element in $\mathcal{P}$ is prime such that all non-quadratic residues are bigger than $N^{\epsilon},$ in particular the smallest one.

I think there's a typo in the last line of the proof.(The denominator should be $S(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{P},\Omega).$) However, you can argue as follows:

$$\#\{p \leq N^{1/2} : n_p > N^{\epsilon}\} = \sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}} 1 \ \le 2 \sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\le 4S(z) \le \frac{8N}{S(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{P},\Omega)} <<_{\epsilon} 1.$$

The first inequality follows from the fact that for all $p\ge 2,$ $1-1/p \ge 1/2.$
The second inequality is in page 3, which follows from the Sieve.
The third inequality also follows from the Sieve.

Comment: you may find this question also interesting :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4424572/estimating-reducible-monic-polynomials-of-degree-n-with-integer-coefficients-of

Comment: 1st inequality of 2nd proof is not clear to me . I understand how $p\geq 2$ and $1-1/p \geq 1/2$. But still how is $ \sum_{p\in P} \leq 2 ...$?

Comment: $ 1-1/p \geq 1/2  \iff  1 \le 2 (1-1/p) $, take sum on both sides
$ \sum 1  \le  \sum  2 (1-1/p) $